# "abandoning samyojanas" vs "removing saṅkhāras"

Tags: stream-entry, sankhara, fetters

When researching stream-entry, I came across this fascinating statement ...

> "The stream enterer ... has removed the saṅkhāras that force rebirth
> in lower planes".

SOURCE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_awakening#Stream-enterer

I find this statement to be fascinating because
the 4 stages of enlightenment are usually described as a function of
"abandoning fetters (samyojanas)"
rather than
"removal of saṅkhāras".

Does this statement have any reference in the suttas?

i.e. Do the suttas actually make this connection between "removing saṅkhāras" and freedom from "rebirth in lower planes"?

If so, do they hint at the nature of the "saṅkhāras" to be removed?

Comment: An interesting viewpoint. When sanyojana breaks in your mind (as you see through them) the practice of sankhara will be valueless to you. In that sense, can't we view these two as cause and effect? ergo, use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'll find these suttas relevant.

- [AN 6.89](https://suttacentral.net/an6.89/en/sujato) through AN 6.91 list six things that are given up, in order to become accomplished in view -- which include the first three fetters (which are abandoned by a stream-enterer).
- Continuing in the same vein, [AN 6.93 says](https://suttacentral.net/an6.93/en/sujato),

  > A person accomplished in view can’t take conditions to be permanent, happiness, or self.

  The word which Ven. Sujato translates there as "conditions" is "sankhara".

Or perhaps that doesn't answer the question, because it's not exactly "removing" sankharas.

On the subject of what might be "a sankhara to be removed", I suspect that identity-view is one example of a sankhara -- in the sense that it's "a fabrication" -- see the simile of the chariot.

Also [AN 4.10](https://suttacentral.net/an4.10/en/sujato) seems to warns against relishing and attaching to views in general:

> And what is the attachment to views?
> It’s when you don’t truly understand views’ origin, ending, gratification, drawback, and escape.
> So greed, relishing, affection, infatuation, thirst, passion, attachment, and craving for views linger on inside.

Perhaps there's some controversy about abandoning views: "Does that mean, all views? What about Right View, surely that's not to be abandoned?" Perhaps that is (ironically) a kind of topic that may lead to differences of view or doctrine between different schools. I suppose that everyone agrees, though, that at least (among all views) "self-views" or "identity view" is to be abandoned by a stream enterer.